# Stop Itunes from transferring purchases to computer iOS 8

Tags: itunes, macos, ipad

How can I stop iTunes from transferring purchases from my ipad ? I just want to backup everything besides the apps since they can always be downloaded back from iTunes store and I do not want to waste my macbook space.

Thanks

Comment: Similar question to this one http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25334/how-do-i-tell-itunes-not-to-back-up-apps